# tkinter canvas image not displaying

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a simple canvas being created in a function, and i would like an image displayed on the canvas.

```
def start(root):
    startframe = tkinter.Frame(root)
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(startframe,width=1280,height=720)

    startframe.pack()
    canvas.pack()

    one = tkinter.PhotoImage('images\one.gif')
    canvas.create_image((0,0),image=one,anchor='nw')
```

when i run the code i get a blank 1280x720 window, no image.

i have looked at the following website: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm but i do not understand how to apply their example to my situation (i dont know what to create a reference to or how to create a reference, if that is my problem). I have also looked at some stack overflow questions but they did not help either.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

1. Escape backslashes in path string correctly. (or use `r'raw string literal'`).
2. Prevent PhotoImage object being garbage collected.
3. specify the filename using `file=...` option.

---

```
def start(root):
    startframe = tkinter.Frame(root)
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(startframe,width=1280,height=720)

    startframe.pack()
    canvas.pack()

    # Escape / raw string literal
    one = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=r'images\one.gif')
    root.one = one  # to prevent the image garbage collected.
    canvas.create_image((0,0), image=one, anchor='nw')
```

**UPDATE**

The two statements `one = ...`  and `root.one = one` can be merged into one statement:

```
    root.one = one = tkinter.PhotoImage(r'images\one.gif')
```

Comment: `root.one = one = tkinter....` is a common idiom to both save and use a local name for an object.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, I updated the answer to mention it. Thank you for comment.  BTW using `root.one = one = ...`, assign to `root.one` occur first. http://ideone.com/OMNeDy

Comment: i'm still getting no image?

Comment: @Thedudxo, I updated the answer: you need to specify the image filepath as a keyword argument `one = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=r'images\one.gif')`

Comment: Why were the images being garbage collected? When does that occur? (This fixed my problem instantly, so I want to know why the main logic in OP's post creates this condition)

Comment: @Sawyer, `one` is local variable. It's garbage collected when the function (where the local variable define) returns.

Comment: Just like @waternake - preventing garbage collection of the PhotoImage fixed it - thank you! 
But why were the images being garbage collected?   I expected the Canvas to hold onto the image.  The second I made the PhotoImage global and held onto the reference everything started working.  VERY strange that the Canvas wouldn't hold onto the image it was given.

Comment: Thinking about this more, I believe what is happening is the underlying C/C++ TK library does indeed have a reference to the PhotoImage, but Python looses its reference at the end of the function, garbage-collects its projection of the TK C++ PhotoImage, which then calls into the C++ library to release that PhotoImage.  Et voilà!   No image in your canvas!

Answer (score 1):

How about `canvas.update()`?  I was suffering a similar problem. I am using grid, so instead of `.pack` I needed to use `.update`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the situation when image didn`t show up, when I call it in function, but otherwise everything was okay. That is my function

```
def ask_for_file():
    f_types = [('PNG Images', '*.png')]
    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=f_types)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=filename)
    canvas.config(height=img.height(), width=img.width())
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=img)
```

My solution was to add `img = None` as global variable and change it inside function. It worked

```
img = None


def ask_for_file():
    global img
    f_types = [('PNG Images', '*.png')]
    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=f_types)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=filename)
    canvas.config(height=img.height(), width=img.width())
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=img)
```